# How can I replace unknown values in known positions in a line?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have *one* solution to the *specific* problem I faced, but it is quite hacky and not at all portable:

```
crontab -l > my-crontab
command='~/test.sh'
minute=1
hour=2
sed -i 's#[0-9]\+ [0-9]\+ [*]\+ [*]\+ [*]\+ '"$command"'#'"$minute"' '"$hour"' * * * '"$command"'#g' my-crontab
crontab my-crontab
```

If I have a line in my crontab that reads, for example, `61 25 * * * ~/test.sh`, the above solution will correctly replace that **entire** line with `1 2 * * * ~/test.sh`, where I have of course hard-coded the format of the entire line.

More generally, then, how can I find any line that contains a known string in an unknown position and then *only* replace the first two columns of that line?

Test case: my-crontab contains many lines and at least one of them looks like one of these:

```
61 25 (gibberish of unknown format that contains the string ~/test.sh and more)
* 25 (gibberish of unknown format that contains the string ~/test.sh and more)
61 * (gibberish of unknown format that contains the string ~/test.sh and more)
```

A working general solution will find any line containing string ~/test.sh and replace the first two columns:

```
1 2 (gibberish of unknown format that contains the string ~/test.sh and more)
```

I have accepted an answer below using sed and extended regex, but I would still be interested to learn of a solution making use of awk column syntax, i.e. $1 $2

Comment: Please, post a testable sample with related expected output, edit them to your post, do not post them as comments or images. Thanks.

Comment: I would just have added `# autofoobar` after the command to make it easily recognizable, then simply filter it out and re-add it: `{ crontab -l | grep -v autofoobar; echo "$minute $hour * * * $command # autofoobar"; } | crontab -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pattern before the `s` command to restrict it to just lines that match that pattern.

Then only replace the beginning of the line in the `s///` command.

```
crontab -l > my-crontab
command='~/test.sh'
minute=1
hour=2
sed -i -r "\\#$command#s#^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+)#$minute $hour#gm" my-crontab
crontab my-crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v min="$minute" -v hrs="$hour" -v scr="$command" '$6 == scr { $1=min;$2=hrs }1' my-crontab > my-crontab.tmp && mv -f my-crontab.tmp my-crontab
```

Pass minute and hour and command variables to awk as min amd hrs and scr. Where the 6th space delimited field is the same as scr, se the first field to min and the second to hrs. Print all lines along with amendments to a temp file and replace the master file with temp.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. I can't know that the string I am searching for will be in the 6th column (or any specific column) and I have edited the question to reflect this.